# How old is Wonder Woman?

Tags: character, dc-extended-universe, wonder-woman

In the movie Wonder Woman, we see Wonder Woman as a child who grows into an adult. During the same time we see the people around her - the Amazons - not seem to age at all. It's revealed that Wonder Woman is special.

> She's actually a God and presumably immortal

The Amazons are, well, not quite human, but they aren't the same as WW.

It's also revealed that:

> A long time ago there was a war between the Gods and all of them perished by the hands of Ares. Before Zeus died, he created Wonder Woman out of clay.

All of the Amazons have bronze aged weaponry and do not seem aware of the changes to the outside world. *This suggests that they are several thousand years old*.

Presumably Wonder Woman has a normal life span as a child and has just become an adult at the beginning of the film. This seems very incongruent to me. Maybe I missed something though.

So, does the film or the DC Extended Universe give any indication of how old Wonder Woman is? Or is my assumption that she's several thousand years old (based on the weaponry) correct, despite the apparent incongruity I brought up?

Comment: Someone could copy and paste [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/155753/70236) for free rep.

Comment: Do NOT copy and paste answers unless you are the OP of the source answer.

Comment: @phantom42 OP will not going to answer here and if you attribute the original creator and give your own input with it, seems fair usage.

Comment: re-writing the answer with your own take is one thing, copy/pasting is another.

Comment: @phantom42 that's why I said "and give your own input with it"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Wonder Woman's age varies.  In [this interview](http://screenrant.com/wonder-woman-age-director-patty-jenkins/), the director can't even pin it down:

> “Well, I think she’s thousands of years old. Really, I think she’s a
>   child but she’s probably 800 [years old].”

[Warner Brothers doesn't appear to know, exactly](http://www.criticalhit.net/entertainment/director-patty-jenkins-reveals-wonder-womans-age-kills-movies-unexpected-editing-process/), either:

> Jenkins does go on to explain that this is merely her opinion of
>   Diana’s age, and that there are others at Warner Bros. who feel
>   differently.

The [Wikia](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Wonder_Woman_(Diana_Prince)) (OK, it's a Wikia, but whatever...  :oP) states they were born, as a race, in 1200BC, which would make her younger than 3200 years old.

However, she wasn't born a full-grown Amazonian.  Comic books and movies have a hard time translating this to on-screen action.  You most likely have seen Wolverine and his origin stories, so you know both Wolverine and Sabretooth started out as children and, at some point, just stopped aging.  Wonder Woman's origin follows a similar path on-screen.

But keep in mind that the movie Wonder Woman was intended to focus on just one point in time.  A quote taken from the 2nd link provided above:

> Oh my God, have I had that conversation. Ad nauseam. Because the truth
>   was I kept talking about listen, this is her coming of age story. How
>   is she coming of age and how long does that take to learn these
>   lessons.

Comment: Wikipedia says she's 5,000 years but there's no source for that number.

Comment: Yeah, so the correct answer is "Somewhere between 800 and 5,000 years old."  :o)